# python2.7, graphviz

Tags: машинное-обучение, python-2.7, graphviz

Возникла проблема при построении графика древа для машинного обучения

```
import StringIO
import os
import numpy as np
import pydotplus

from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38'


def make_pdf(percent, m_classifier):
    dot_data = StringIO.StringIO()
    tree.export_graphviz(m_classifier, out_file=dot_data)
    graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
    graph.write_png("graph" + str(percent) + ".png")

experiments = [
    [1, 60, 40],
    [2, 70, 30],
    [3, 80, 20]
]

for experiment in experiments:
    trainPercent = experiment[1]

    print "Experiment : #", experiment[0], "trainPercent =", trainPercent, "%"

imported_data = []
k = 0



for line in open('mammographic_masses1.data', 'r'):
    line = line.split(",")

    newline = []
    for item in line:
        if item == "?":
            newline.append(0)
        else:
            newline.append(item)

    line = map(int, newline)
    imported_data.append(line)

all_data = np.array(imported_data)

X = all_data[:, :5]
y = all_data[:, 5]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=trainPercent / 100.0)
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predicted = clf.predict(X_test)

print y_predicted
guessed_num = 0

for ind in range(0, len(y_predicted)):
    if y_predicted[ind] == y_test[ind]:
        guessed_num += 1

print "TOTAL:", len(y_test)
print "guessed:", guessed_num
print "accuracy:", 1.0 * guessed_num / len(y_test)
make_pdf(trainPercent, clf)
```

Консоль:

```
C:\Users\mihail\Anaconda2\python.exe "E:/Lab - 1/main.py"
Experiment : # 1 trainPercent = 60 %
Experiment : # 2 trainPercent = 70 %
Experiment : # 3 trainPercent = 80 %
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
C:\Users\mihail\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py:2026: FutureWarning: From version 0.21, test_size will always complement train_size unless both are specified.
  FutureWarning)
 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1
 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1]
TOTAL: 193
guessed: 142
accuracy: 0.735751295337
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Lab - 1/main.py", line 64, in <module>
    make_pdf(trainPercent, clf)
  File "E:/Lab - 1/main.py", line 17, in make_pdf
    graph.write_png("graph" + str(percent) + ".png")
  File "C:\Users\mihail\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 1810, in <lambda>
    prog=self.prog: self.write(path, format=f, prog=prog)
  File "C:\Users\mihail\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 1918, in write
    fobj.write(self.create(prog, format))
  File "C:\Users\mihail\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 1960, in create
    'GraphViz\'s executables not found')
pydotplus.graphviz.InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Я как понимаю что он не видит мои файлы. Но я устанавливал graphviz с сайта разработчиков и прописал путь к нему.

P.S. Мой уровень питона - джуниор, 50 метров вниз и потом только я.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438997/why-is-pydot-unable-to-find-graphvizs-executables-in-windows-8